# Mulitple Lines in a single Excel cell

Tags: python

What is the easiest method for writing multple lines into a single cell within excel using python. Ive trying the csv module without success.

```
import csv
with open('xyz.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
  w = csv.writer(outfile)
  w.writerow(['stringa','string_multiline',])
```

Also each of the mutliline stringshave a number of characters in which are typically used for csv`s ie commas.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To figure this out, I created a file in Excel with a single multiline cell.

[image]

Then I saved it as CSV and opened it up in a text editor:

```
"a^Mb"
```

It looks like Excel interprets Ctrl-M characters as newlines.

Let’s try that with Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import csv

with open('xyz.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
      w = csv.writer(outfile)
      w.writerow(['stringa','multiline\015string',])
```

Yup, that worked!

[image]

Comment: "Ctrl-M characters"... also known as carriage returns.  :-)

Comment: Thanks but I must be getting confused somewhere along the lines. I tried what you suggested but when I import it into excel it just adds them to separate cells. I tried using ctl-M,\015 but each time it doesnt appear to work like the above. Any further help would be great....

Comment: @felix001 On Excel 2010 in Windows, it seems to need `\r\n` instead of `\015` = `\r`, but the row doesn’t automatically expand to show both lines of the string. You need to size the row manually to see both lines. But then Excel Mac 2011 shows the `\n` after  the `\r` as an extra space at the start of the second line—so there may be no cross-platform solution using `.csv` files. This is the sort of portability problem that XML was designed for. I’ve had good luck with [`openpyxl`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl) for reading/writing .xlsx files directly, maybe you could try that?

Comment: OK great the \r\n & python csv module worked a treat. Thaks for for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass extra double quotes (") at the start and end of the string. Seperate the different lines of the cell using newline character (\n) .
e.g "line1\nline2\nline3"

```
f=open("filename.csv","w")
f.write("\"line1\nline2\nline3\"")`
```

[The code creates this csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lR7wp.png)