# Python: Add Line breaks into Excel cells while exporting the DataFrame

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have the following `df`, where there are new line characters `\n` in column `Data`, as shown below.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['111', '222', '222'],
                   'Data': ['Population\nDensity','Population\nDensity','Population\nDensity\nArea']})
print(df)

    ID  Data
0   111 Population\nDensity
1   222 Population\nDensity
2   222 Population\nDensity\nArea
```

While exporting this `df` to Excel, I want line breaks at `\n`. It should look like:

[image: Excel]

I sought some help from [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562977/xlsxwriter-text-wrap-not-working), using `xlsxwriter` but didn't work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use xlsxwriter as the Excel writing engine you can add a text wrap format to the column like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['111', '222', '222'],
                   'Data': ['Population\nDensity',
                            'Population\nDensity',
                            'Population\nDensity\nArea']})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Add a text wrap format.
text_wrap_format = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True})

# Add the format to column 2 (zero-indexed) and adjust the width.
worksheet.set_column(1, 1, 15, text_wrap_format)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.close()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just one question - In `to_excel()` function, if `index=False` is removed, then we don't get line breaks. Why?

Comment: Probably you need to adjust the column number index in `set_column()` to 2 to account for the extra column.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't always work. :(

Comment: doesn't work for me either.

Comment: To the folks saying this doesn't work I would suggest suggest opening a new question with sample code.

Comment: I'm getting AttributeError: `'XlsxWriter' object has no attribute 'save'`

Comment: @emilaz See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76119258/10238

Answer (score 0):

Replace \n with `CHAR(10)` as per here: https://exceljet.net/formula/add-a-line-break-with-a-formula

Comment: I want a Python solution.

Comment: @cph_sto you may have better luck with this solution then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17279740/14852056